# Newbie MVC - DropDownList + edit button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm trying to learn mvc and cannot fathom this ->
I have to EF Models.
Customer and Order
one to many relationship yada yada bla bla...
Customer PK = ID. Orders FK = c_ID.
I want my View to have a dropdownlist with a list of customers and an edit button.
when you click the edit button, you edit the Orders for the selected customer.
the dropdownlist gets populated just fine with the SurName of the customer

my View:

```
...
<p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit"))
    {
        @Html.DropDownList("Customers", "Select Customer")
        <button type="submit">Edit</button>
    }
</p>
...
```

and the controller (I've put a breakpoint to see if the correct id gets returned by the button).

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Customers= new SelectList(db.Customers,"ID", "Name");
            return View();
        }
   public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
        {

           //Need to return list of orders from c_ID
        }
```

When I click my button, nothing happens it just appends "/length=4" to the url.
what am I missing?

I bet this is something very simple, and I'll properly feel VERY stupid once someone gives me the answer, anyways :) thanks for your help

Comment: This is most likely a routing problem. What do the routes in your Global.asax.cs file look like?

Comment: default - routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: I've seen similar urls (with `?length=X` instead of the id) when trying to pass strings as the `id` parameter. What happens if you change `Edit(int id)` to `Edit(string id)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Value" attribute of button/ to pass the actionresult name